# What is the difference between Athan and Iqamah?

Tags: salat, prayer-timings, adhan

Athan is the call to prayer. Informing people that the beginning of the specific time (dhuhr or asr for example) has begun.

I am not sure what Iqamah is because I heard calling from the mosque 20 minutes after athan then found out it is Iqamah. Is iqamah a second athan? Or is iqamah calling people to the mosque for congregational prayer? Does iqamah only apply to the mosque?

(Sorry for not understanding. I'm still learning.)

Comment: Adhan basically is the call for prayer which usually is intended to gather people to a location to pray in a given time, while iqamah is performed right before the prayer so it is a call to gather the people around to stand up to pray... there are other differences which were quoted in the given answers. It is recommended to correctly and fully pronounce the word of iqamah (for example saying Allahu akbaru..)

Comment: Use  google seaech

Answer (score 1):

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

**Adhan** is called to bring people to a place of congregation - mosque. It indicates that time for a prayer has started. So after hearing the **Adhan** one, if he is not in a state of ritual purity, should do his Wudu and come to mosque. Adhan is recited loudly from the mosque, traditionally from the [minaret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minaret).

See also

- [Wikipedia - Adhan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adhan)

**Iqama** is called in place of congregation to summon people, who have come to the place of congregation, to start Salah. After **Iqama** is called people should form rows behind the Imam. **The iqama** is given in a more rapid and less sonorous rendering than the first call, the adhan, because it is intended merely to draw the attention of those already in the mosque, rather than to remind those outside the mosque to come in.

See also

- [Wikipedia - Iqama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iqama)

Comment: This may leave the impression that adhan is related to mosque while it is even recommended anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Iqamah is also a call to prayer, specifically it is calling those who are present to actually start the prayer. The wording of Iqamah is almost the same as the wording of adhan with the following differences:

- The phrase قد قامت الصلاة is added after حي على الفلاح
- The number of times the phrases are repeated is different according to some madhabs, see [here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/10458).
- Iqamah is to be said at a quick pace unlike adhan.

Note that both Adhan and Iqamah can be said for any prayer, not necessarily one being offered in a mosque.

Ref: https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/5431/

Comment: @Medi1Saif Clarified that.